# Loop through a collection push each item to a new collection based on action property

Tags: javascript, loops

so for example I have this collection:

```
var items = [
{accntNumber: 12345, action: "Non Derogatory", bureau: "TU",      username: "pbutler"},
{accntNumber: 785, action: "Deleted", bureau: "EXP", username: "areston"},
{accntNumber: 956, action: "Deleted", bureau: "TU", username: "nikkim"},
{accntNumber: 1235, action: " 100% Non Derogatory", bureau: "TU", username: "ajaquez"},
{accntNumber: 45336, action: "Non Derogatory", bureau: "TU", username: "nikkim"},
{accntNumber: 845, action: "Newly Negative", bureau: "TU", username: "areston"},
{accntNumber: 9875, action: "No Longer On Report", bureau: "TU", username: "ajaquez"}
]
```

And I want to loop through it and find the "action" key and push the entire object to the corresponding array:
So for examples the deleted items should go in the deleted array, the non Derogatory items, should all go in the nonDerogatoryItems array.

```
var nonDerogatoryItems = [];
var deleted = [];
var _100nonDerogatoryItems = [];
var newlyNegative = [];
var noLongerOnReport = [];
```

Comment: Sounds like a fun project. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

If you **do not** wish to use any libraries, there is a pretty simple way to accomplish what you want using **plain JavaScript** only:

```
// Assuming you already declared 'items' with it's objects
var nonDerogatoryItems = deleted = _100nonDerogatoryItems = newlyNegative = noLongerOnReport = undefinedActionArray = [];

for(var i in items){
  switch(items[i].action){
    case 'Deleted':
      deleted.push(items[i]);
      break;
    case 'Newly Negative':
      newlyNegative.push(items[i]);
      break;

    // [...] and so on for the other possible actions

    // In case any action goes missing (doesn't match the switch), you can debug this and check 
    // what happened, if there was any mistype or so
    default:
      undefinedActionArray.push(items[i]);
      break;
  }
}
```

---

Now if you're looking into working with fewer lines but a bit more complexity, this is what you could do:

```
var actions = [];
for(var i in items){

    // If this action wasn't set yet
    if(typeof actions[items[i].action] === 'undefined')
      actions[items[i].action] = []; // Starts as an empty array

    // Now pushes the current item into it's group
    actions[items[i].action].push(items[i]);

}
```

That would end up resulting into something like this:

```
actions = [
  "Deleted" = [
    {accntNumber: 785, action: "Deleted", bureau: "EXP", username: "areston"},
    {accntNumber: 956, action: "Deleted", bureau: "TU", username: "nikkim"}
  ],
  "Non Derogatory" = [
    {accntNumber: 12345, action: "Non Derogatory", bureau: "TU",      username: "pbutler"},
    {accntNumber: 45336, action: "Non Derogatory", bureau: "TU", username: "nikkim"}
  ],
  // [...] And so forth
]
```

### Bottomline

The **first** example is simpler, yet you will have a large script depending on the amount of `actions` that exists. Also, whenever a new `action` type comes up you'll need to update your code.

The **second** example is more dynamic and adapts to changes. With a few lines you'll always work out all possible `actions` that might exists into `items`'s objects.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked great!!! I am using Angular, so I would have inject lodash. Maybe latter, as I think its very convenient!

Comment: Glad to help @FernandaSilva ! Please consider checking the answer as correct if this solved your problem, so this question won't be listed as "Unanswered". Also, you could have specified in your question that you're using Angular, that probably would have refined the answers accordingly.

Comment: Sounds good!!! This was actually my first question here, so I don't think I can upvote your answer, sorry. Thank you for the hints, I will give more details on future posts.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use your favorite functional library.

```
groupedItems = _.groupBy(items, 'action')

groupedItems.Deleted.length // 2
```

This one's good https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy